# Picking up information from remote website

Tags: php, regex

I'm picking up information from a remote website and I'm stuck with this bit of html:

```
<div>
        <a onclick="javascripthere" href="#">
            <img width="110" height="160" alt="" src="imageurlhere">
            {variable sized string}
        </a>
        <br>2012/01/10 17:35:20<br>
        <img alt="{variable sized string}" src="imageurlhere">
</div>
```

From the above html i need to pick up the 2 "{variable sized string}". They can be any type of character (a-zA-Z0-9 and spaces / other characters), and i can't figure out what kind of regex or php to use to get those two strings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/328193).

Use a [DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).  It will make your development *much* simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) to do this instead of using regular expressions, which are not ideal for parsing HTML or XML. Your code will be much cleaner and easier to read for a start.

For example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body><img alt="{variable sized string}" src="imageurlhere"></body></html>");
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('alt');
}
```

There are a number of projects that wrap DOMDocument with easier APIs such as [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (jQuery like selectors to navigate the DOM) and [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$preg_match("/<img.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/", $string, $match);

//$match[1] is your first string

$preg_match("/<img alt=\"(.*?)\"/", $string, $match2);

//match2[1] is your second string.
```